# Shift lever and rear derailleur compatibility

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, derailleur, shifter

I have got MTB with Shimano RD-M410 Alivio Rear Derailleur 8 speed. It has  brake/shift lever for it model ST-EF50-8R. I would like to move to disc brakes and therefore want to change to ST-EF505 shift/brake lever. Does anyone know if it is compatible with the Alivio RD-M410 rear derailleur?

Actually I plan on buying the 8 speed version of the st-ef505-r. https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/acera-m3000/ST-EF505-8R.html Does it have the same cable pull as the st-ef50-8r?

Comment: If you're trying to convert a bike with a frame designed for rim brakes to disk brakes, [that isn't possible](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/72015/disk-brakes-swap-on-a-new-road-bike-with-rim-brakes/72019).

Comment: that answer is not exactly relevant, as some v-brake MTBs have frames and forks ready for disc brakes. however this project is still likely a bad idea....

Comment: One can mix brake systems on a MTB that isn't disc brake ready by installing a disc brake fork with a disc front wheel. Then you'd have a bike capable of having disc brake in front and keep the V-brake in the rear.

Comment: I must, however, take this opportunity (again) to express my discontent with disc brake systems.  Due to the MUCH higher cost (in both hardware and ongoing maintenance), frequent noise issues, the ridiculous sensitivity to pad contamination, and by and large, only a modest performance boost over quality V-brakes, there is no reason that is both compelling AND logical to make a move to disc brakes--especially on a bike that isn't equipped to use disc brakes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use any Shimano 8 speed shifter with a Shimano 8 speed derailleur and cassette.

Generally Shimano (and SRAM) used the same sprocket spacing for all cassettes with the same number of sprockets (more sprockets means narrower spacing though). All MTB shifters up to 9 speed use the same *cable actuation ratio* (ratio of cable pulled to cage movement), and all shifters pull the right amount of cable per shift for the number of speeds they are for.

Answer (score 1):

For readers, the ST-EF505-R is a 9 speed shifter with hydraulic brake lever combined. The cable pull on 8 and 9 speed is the same, so you will be able to use the ST-EF505-R on your bike.

While there is nothing inherently wrong with combined units, personally I prefer a separate brake and shifter. If you are buying disc brakes it may work out cheaper to by a complete brake set and then a suitable shifter, so its an option certainly worth considering.

I suggest before proceeding familiarize yourself with the many discussions here and elsewhere about disc brake upgrades, in terms of both difficulties and cost.  Properly setup quality V brakes with good pads can be very effective.

Comment: A 9 speed shifter cannot be used on an 8 speed system. The *cable actuation ratio* (ratio of cable pulled to cage movement) is the same but a 9 speed shifter pulls less cable per shift to account for 9 speed narrower sprocket spacing

Comment: This is not correct; ST-EF505-R exists in 3 right-hand versions for 7, 8 and 9 speeds, and while -L has two versions for double or triple shifters. The OP refers to ST-EF505-8R, which is the correct version for 8-speed.